# Is there a way to chain calls in Bitcoin core console?

Tags: client

Is there a way to chain calls in Bitcoin core client console window like this

```
validateaddress (getaccountaddress "")
```

instead of

```
getaccountaddress ""
validateaddress _address from previous call_
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is not. The API is quite simple.

Comment: Chaining is not really a good practice, if anything fails in between the commands you have zero control over the exception handling.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `$()` syntax to execute another command and have it return its results:

`validateaddress $(getaccountaddress "")`

Here's the docs: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution